# Use curry to increment a value until it is equal to another value

Tags: javascript

I've been working to wrap my head around currying in JavaScript and am not sure how to get multiple calls to a curried function to return the increment of the value passed into the function.

Here is my code:

```js
function curryFunc(x) {
  var index = x;
  var tmp;

  return function(y) {
    tmp = y;
    index++;

    if (index < tmp) {
      console.log('index < y. index =',index);
    } else {
      console.log('end');
      return;
    }
  }
};

var read = curryFunc(1);

var test = read(3); 
test(); // 'index < y. index = 2'
test(); // This returns an error: js:32 Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function
```

How can I get `test` to continue to log the increment of `x` until it is equal to `y`?

Comment: I'm not sure this is relevant to understand currying. A curried function is a function that can partially apply itself, that's pretty much it, it has nothing to do with side-effects, I think that will confuse you more.

Comment: Thanks! I'll update the question. I was thinking that the returned function's parameter would would be stored in stored in the `tmp` variable and could be accessed with each subsequent call.  I'm not sure why that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: You seem to be asking about closures more than currying...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you're not reading *your* code, and the resulting output and exception correctly.

Here's what's really happening:

```js
function curryFunc(x) {
  var index = x;
  var tmp;

  return function(y) {
    tmp = y;
    index++;

    if (index < tmp) {
      console.log('index < y. index =',index);
    } else {
      console.log('end');
      return;
    }
  }
};

var read = curryFunc(1);

var test = read(3); // 'index < y. index = 2'
test(); // This returns an error: js:32 Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function
test(); // This never happens because of the exception above
```

What you probably wanted to do is:

```js
function curryFunc(x) {
  var index = x;
  var tmp;

  return function(y) {
    tmp = y;
    return function() {
      index++;

      if (index < tmp) {
        console.log('index < y. index =',index);
      } else {
        console.log('end');
        return;
      }
    }
  }
};

var read = curryFunc(1);

var test = read(3);
test();
test();
```

And this too is not exactly currying, it's just awkward closures.

But really, you shouldn't be writing code like this. If you really need currying, use a library.

Comment: Thank you!  You are absolutely right and I can't believe I my mistake in how the values were being logged in the console.  Thank you for the example, I was thinking that the if-statement would need to have another function to return to it but wasn't sure if I was grasping that fully.  I don't think I would need to write code like this, but currying is something I recently was reading about and wanted to see if I could make an example that used it too wrap my mind around it.  Thanks for the great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `test` is not a function. The first line printed out is printed by the line `var test = read(3);` and the first call to `test` causes the error. You would have to call the `read` function repeatedly. Perhaps you want to do this:

```
var read = curryFunc(1);
function test() {
    read(3);
}
test();
test();
```